# unicode displayed inconsistently across different programs

Tags: c++, unicode, utf-8, cjk

I'm working on [some library for pretty-printing tables](https://github.com/kindlychung/variadic_table_conan) using [unicode box-drawing characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box-drawing_character), and encountered some strange behaviors in terms of displaying of these characters. Here are some screenshots:

In terminal, with noto sans mono font (looks normal):

[image]

In gvim, with fira code (also normal):

[image]

In vscode, with noto sans mono:

[image]

In firefox, force noto sans mono:

[image]

In firefox, allow github.com choose fonts:

[image]

In chrome:

[image]

OS: Ubuntu 18.10

Settings in my .bash_profile:

```
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
export LC_ALL="en_US.UTF-8"
export LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
export LC_NUMERIC=en_US.UTF-8
export LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8
export LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
export LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8
export LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
export LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8
export LC_NAME=en_US.UTF-8
export LC_ADDRESS=en_US.UTF-8
export LC_TELEPHONE=en_US.UTF-8
export LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8
export LC_IDENTIFICATION=en_US.UTF-8
```

Could anyone help me understand what is going wrong here?

hex dump of the text:

```
00000000: e295 92e2 9590 e295 90e2 9590 e295 90e2  ................
00000010: 9590 e295 90e2 9590 e295 90e2 9590 e295  ................
00000020: 90e2 9590 e295 90e2 9590 e295 90e2 9590  ................
00000030: e295 90e2 9590 e295 90e2 9590 e295 90e2  ................
00000040: 9590 e295 90e2 9590 e295 90e2 9590 e295  ................
00000050: 90e2 9590 e295 90e2 9590 e295 90e2 9590  ................
00000060: e295 90e2 9590 e295 90e2 9590 e295 90e2  ................
00000070: 9590 e295 950a e294 8220 4e61 6d65 2020  ......... Name  
00000080: 2020 5765 6967 6874 2020 2020 2020 2020    Weight        
00000090: 2041 6765 2020 4272 6f74 6865 7220 e294   Age  Brother ..
000000a0: 820a e294 9ce2 9480 e294 80e2 9480 e294  ................
000000b0: 80e2 9480 e294 80e2 9480 e294 80e2 9480  ................
000000c0: e294 80e2 9480 e294 80e2 9480 e294 80e2  ................
000000d0: 9480 e294 80e2 9480 e294 80e2 9480 e294  ................
000000e0: 80e2 9480 e294 80e2 9480 e294 80e2 9480  ................
000000f0: e294 80e2 9480 e294 80e2 9480 e294 80e2  ................
00000100: 9480 e294 80e2 9480 e294 80e2 9480 e294  ................
00000110: 80e2 9480 e294 a40a e294 8220 436f 6479  ........... Cody
00000120: 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 3138 302e              180.
00000130: 3220 2020 3430 2020 4a6f 686e 2020 2020  2   40  John    
00000140: e294 820a e294 8220 4461 7669 6420 2020  ....... David   
00000150: 2020 2020 2020 2020 3137 352e 3320 2020          175.3   
00000160: 3338 2020 416e 6472 6577 2020 e294 820a  38  Andrew  ....
00000170: e294 8220 526f 6265 7274 2020 2020 2020  ... Robert      
00000180: 2020 2020 3134 302e 3320 2020 3237 2020      140.3   27  
00000190: 4661 6e64 6520 2020 e294 820a e294 94e2  Fande   ........
000001a0: 9480 e294 80e2 9480 e294 80e2 9480 e294  ................
000001b0: 80e2 9480 e294 80e2 9480 e294 80e2 9480  ................
000001c0: e294 80e2 9480 e294 80e2 9480 e294 80e2  ................
000001d0: 9480 e294 80e2 9480 e294 80e2 9480 e294  ................
000001e0: 80e2 9480 e294 80e2 9480 e294 80e2 9480  ................
000001f0: e294 80e2 9480 e294 80e2 9480 e294 80e2  ................
00000200: 9480 e294 80e2 9480 e294 80e2 9480 e294  ................
00000210: 980a e295 92e2 9590 e295 90e2 9590 e295  ................
00000220: 90e2 9590 e295 90e2 9590 e295 90e2 9590  ................
00000230: e295 90e2 9590 e295 90e2 9590 e295 90e2  ................
00000240: 9590 e295 90e2 9590 e295 90e2 9590 e295  ................
00000250: 90e2 9590 e295 90e2 9590 e295 90e2 9590  ................
00000260: e295 90e2 9590 e295 90e2 9590 e295 90e2  ................
00000270: 9590 e295 90e2 9590 e295 90e2 9590 e295  ................
00000280: 90e2 9590 e295 90e2 9590 e295 90e2 9590  ................
00000290: e295 90e2 9590 e295 90e2 9590 e295 90e2  ................
000002a0: 9590 e295 90e2 9590 e295 90e2 9590 e295  ................
000002b0: 90e2 9590 e295 90e2 9590 e295 90e2 9590  ................
000002c0: e295 90e2 9590 e295 90e2 9590 e295 90e2  ................
000002d0: 9590 e295 90e2 9590 e295 90e2 9590 e295  ................
000002e0: 90e2 9590 e295 90e2 9590 e295 90e2 9590  ................
000002f0: e295 90e2 9590 e295 90e2 9590 e295 90e2  ................
00000300: 9590 e295 90e2 9590 e295 90e2 9590 e295  ................
00000310: 90e2 9590 e295 90e2 9590 e295 90e2 9590  ................
00000320: e295 90e2 9590 e295 90e2 9590 e295 90e2  ................
00000330: 9590 e295 90e2 9590 e295 90e2 9590 e295  ................
00000340: 90e2 9590 e295 90e2 9590 e295 90e2 9590  ................
00000350: e295 950a e294 8220 5365 6374 696f 6e2f  ....... Section/
00000360: e983 a8e5 8886 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020  ......          
00000370: 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020                  
00000380: 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020                  
00000390: 2020 436f 6c31 2fe7 acac 31e6 a08f 2020    Col1/...1...  
000003a0: 2043 6f6c 322f e7ac ac32 e6a0 8f20 2043   Col2/...2...  C
000003b0: 6f6c 332f e7ac ac33 e6a0 8f20 2043 6f6c  ol3/...3...  Col
000003c0: 342f e7ac ac34 e6a0 8f20 e294 820a e294  4/...4... ......
000003d0: 9ce2 9480 e294 80e2 9480 e294 80e2 9480  ................
000003e0: e294 80e2 9480 e294 80e2 9480 e294 80e2  ................
000003f0: 9480 e294 80e2 9480 e294 80e2 9480 e294  ................
00000400: 80e2 9480 e294 80e2 9480 e294 80e2 9480  ................
00000410: e294 80e2 9480 e294 80e2 9480 e294 80e2  ................
00000420: 9480 e294 80e2 9480 e294 80e2 9480 e294  ................
00000430: 80e2 9480 e294 80e2 9480 e294 80e2 9480  ................
00000440: e294 80e2 9480 e294 80e2 9480 e294 80e2  ................
00000450: 9480 e294 80e2 9480 e294 80e2 9480 e294  ................
00000460: 80e2 9480 e294 80e2 9480 e294 80e2 9480  ................
00000470: e294 80e2 9480 e294 80e2 9480 e294 80e2  ................
00000480: 9480 e294 80e2 9480 e294 80e2 9480 e294  ................
00000490: 80e2 9480 e294 80e2 9480 e294 80e2 9480  ................
000004a0: e294 80e2 9480 e294 80e2 9480 e294 80e2  ................
000004b0: 9480 e294 80e2 9480 e294 80e2 9480 e294  ................
000004c0: 80e2 9480 e294 80e2 9480 e294 80e2 9480  ................
000004d0: e294 80e2 9480 e294 80e2 9480 e294 80e2  ................
000004e0: 9480 e294 80e2 9480 e294 80e2 9480 e294  ................
000004f0: 80e2 9480 e294 80e2 9480 e294 80e2 9480  ................
00000500: e294 80e2 9480 e294 80e2 9480 e294 a40a  ................
00000510: e294 8220 e6a0 b9e7 9bae e5bd 9520 2020  ... .........   
00000520: 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020                  
00000530: 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020                  
00000540: 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020                  
00000550: 2034 2e35 3235 652d 3031 2020 2020 2020   4.525e-01      
00000560: 2030 2e30 3532 2020 2020 2020 2020 302e   0.052        0.
00000570: 3036 2020 2020 2020 2d31 2c31 3133 20e2  06      -1,113 .
00000580: 9482 0ae2 9482 20e5 ba94 e794 a83a 3ae5  ...... ......::.
00000590: ae89 e8a3 8520 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020  .....           
000005a0: 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020                  
000005b0: 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020                  
000005c0: 2020 2020 2031 2e33 3330 652b 3030 2020       1.330e+00  
000005d0: 2020 2020 2030 2e30 3337 2020 2020 2020       0.037      
000005e0: 2020 302e 3034 2020 2020 2020 2020 2032    0.04         2
000005f0: 3334 20e2 9482 0ae2 9482 20e5 889d e5a7  34 ....... .....
00000600: 8be5 8c96 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020  ....            
00000610: 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020                  
00000620: 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020                  
00000630: 2020 2020 2020 2020 322e 3535 3165 2b30          2.551e+0
00000640: 3020 2020 2020 2020 302e 3030 3220 2020  0       0.002   
00000650: 2020 2020 2030 2e30 3020 2020 2020 2037       0.00      7
00000660: 372c 3436 3120 e294 820a e294 8220 5079  7,461 ....... Py
00000670: 7468 6f6e e788 ace5 8f96 e68a 96e9 9fb3  thon............
00000680: 4150 502c e7ab 9fe7 84b6 e58f aae9 9c80  APP,............
00000690: e8a6 81e5 8d81 e8a1 8ce4 bba3 e7a0 8120  ............... 
000006a0: 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020                  
000006b0: 2020 2020 2031 2e35 3438 652d 3033 2020       1.548e-03  
000006c0: 2020 2020 2030 2e30 3030 2020 2020 2020       0.000      
000006d0: 2020 302e 3030 2020 2020 2020 3438 2c30    0.00      48,0
000006e0: 3137 20e2 9482 0ae2 9482 20e5 8d83 e4b8  17 ....... .....
000006f0: 87e5 88ab e581 9ae8 8081 e69d bfe6 9c80  ................
00000700: e4b8 8de8 83bd e5ae b9e5 bf8d e79a 84e4  ................
00000710: b889 e7a7 8de4 baba 207a 2020 2020 2020  ........ z      
00000720: 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020                  
00000730: 2020 2020 352e 3130 3065 2d30 3520 2020      5.100e-05   
00000740: 2020 2020 302e 3030 3020 2020 2020 2020      0.000       
00000750: 2030 2e30 3020 2020 202d 3438 332c 3436   0.00    -483,46
00000760: 3120 e294 820a e294 8220 e885 bee8 aeaf  1 ....... ......
00000770: 20e9 98bf e987 8c20 e58d 8ee4 b8ba e79a   ...... ........
00000780: 84e5 b297 e4bd 8de8 96aa e8b5 84e6 8385  ................
00000790: e586 b5e6 a682 e8bf b020 2020 2020 2020  .........       
000007a0: 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020                  
000007b0: 2020 2036 2e37 3030 652d 3035 2020 2020     6.700e-05    
000007c0: 2020 2030 2e30 3032 2020 2020 2020 2020     0.002        
000007d0: 302e 3030 2020 2020 2034 3330 2c30 3631  0.00     430,061
000007e0: 20e2 9482 0ae2 9482 20e7 a88b e5ba 8fe5   ....... .......
000007f0: 9198 e699 92e5 87ba e5b0 8fe5 ada6 e584  ................
00000800: bfe5 ad90 e6bb a1e5 8886 e4bd 9ce6 9687  ................
00000810: e380 8ae6 8891 e79a 84e7 88b8 e788 b8e3  ................
00000820: 808b efbc 8ce7 9c9f e5ae 9ee7 9a84 e8ae  ................
00000830: a9e4 baba e5bf 83e7 96bc 2020 2020 322e  ..........    2.
00000840: 3035 3165 2d30 3320 2020 2020 2020 302e  051e-03       0.
00000850: 3030 3020 2020 2020 2020 2030 2e30 3020  000        0.00 
00000860: 2020 2020 2020 362c 3637 3820 e294 820a        6,678 ....
00000870: e294 94e2 9480 e294 80e2 9480 e294 80e2  ................
00000880: 9480 e294 80e2 9480 e294 80e2 9480 e294  ................
00000890: 80e2 9480 e294 80e2 9480 e294 80e2 9480  ................
000008a0: e294 80e2 9480 e294 80e2 9480 e294 80e2  ................
000008b0: 9480 e294 80e2 9480 e294 80e2 9480 e294  ................
000008c0: 80e2 9480 e294 80e2 9480 e294 80e2 9480  ................
000008d0: e294 80e2 9480 e294 80e2 9480 e294 80e2  ................
000008e0: 9480 e294 80e2 9480 e294 80e2 9480 e294  ................
000008f0: 80e2 9480 e294 80e2 9480 e294 80e2 9480  ................
00000900: e294 80e2 9480 e294 80e2 9480 e294 80e2  ................
00000910: 9480 e294 80e2 9480 e294 80e2 9480 e294  ................
00000920: 80e2 9480 e294 80e2 9480 e294 80e2 9480  ................
00000930: e294 80e2 9480 e294 80e2 9480 e294 80e2  ................
00000940: 9480 e294 80e2 9480 e294 80e2 9480 e294  ................
00000950: 80e2 9480 e294 80e2 9480 e294 80e2 9480  ................
00000960: e294 80e2 9480 e294 80e2 9480 e294 80e2  ................
00000970: 9480 e294 80e2 9480 e294 80e2 9480 e294  ................
00000980: 80e2 9480 e294 80e2 9480 e294 80e2 9480  ................
00000990: e294 80e2 9480 e294 80e2 9480 e294 80e2  ................
000009a0: 9480 e294 80e2 9480 e294 80e2 9480 e294  ................
000009b0: 980a                                     ..
```

Comment: Are you using tabs, spaces or a combination of both to separate the columns?

Comment: Please see the hex dump I just added. @JGNI

Comment: OK so it's utf8 encoded and it's spaces every where. So a mono-spaced font should work.

Comment: Yeah, it should, but it doesn't. Also tested on a macbook pro, same problem.

Comment: You cannot solve this locally. While you *can* suggest fonts to browsers (and you should choose wisely, to cater for not well-endowed systems), the local fallback system for unknown systems and the actual *font* used by those same fallback system is beyond your control. For HTML, create proper tables. For best control, use the ol' `+----+` ASCII borders.